# Webform, Contribution Page & Events - Status always pending

Tags: civievent, webform-civicrm, paypal

Sorry for the long post but I want to provide as much info as possbile:

I am brand new to civicrm but very experienced in drupal. I'm running civi as a subdomain: dogs.mysite.com with drupal 7.57, civi 4.7.31, webform_civicrm 7.x-4.20, php 5.6,

I am adding online registration to a dog training school. I've added Paypal WPS as a processor and I've set it to live to eliminate any issues there. Events have been setup without fees or online registration. I have a Contribution page setup with Paypal selected. I have tested the Contrib page with Test-Drive and it worked. The webform has the Participant Fee Amount hardcoded, has the payment processor selected (Live) and has the Contribution page included.

The webform successfully creates an event participant, but the particpiant status is always "Pending (incomplete transaction)". Paypal IPN history shows a response code of 200; the ipn message looks ok, I can see the IPN post in the civicrm_system_log, the Civicrm.xx.log shows the following (contact & contrib ids are correct)

Apr 02 11:58:37  [info] $IDS Detector Details = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => custom
            [value] => {"module":"contribute","contactID":"27","contributionID":24}
            [page] => /civicrm/payment/ipn/6?
            [userid] => 
            [session] => wLXUsbVoDi_v3KiTLCkT66LvULTkEk0W72oldnOzCKs
            [ip] => 70.39.249.31
            [reaction] => 0
            [impact] => 32
        )

)
Apr 02 11:58:38  [info] Contribution record updated successfully
Apr 02 11:58:38  [info] Success: Database updated

What do I need to do to have the Event Participant status set to Complete?

Thank you!

Bill

Comment: Just on your Paypal setup, have you checked the IPN URL  which should be https://example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/ipn.php (obv http if non-secure)

Comment: How does it work for eg a standard Contribution page with a $1 live donation?

Comment: @TonyHorrocks...I've tried mysite.com, mysite.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/ipn.php and mysite.com/civicrm/payment/ipn/6 (6 is my paypal payment id)

Comment: @petednz-fuzion...a live contribution with a small amount works, the paypal transaction id is shown in the contribution payment details and the status is marked as completed.

Comment: Update....I changed from using webform_civicrm for collecting registration info to using the event's online registration with a modified profile and participants are marked as registered after payment. Since this works, I am giving up on the webform/contrib and just using event.